# Android WebServices PHP MYSQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, web-services

I am trying to save student data from my android app to MYSQL Database via Webservices. But the problem is it is not saving data on the database .. The Php file is programmed in a manner that it will display JSON as output

```
$response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Student record has been saved successfully";
```

else

```
 $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
```

PHP File returning "Oops! An error occurred " in the application..

My PHP File For Creating New Records Is:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['rollno']) && isset($_POST['sname']) && isset($_POST['regid']) &&isset($_POST['class'])&& isset($_POST['fname'])&& isset($_POST['fno'])&& isset($_POST['mname'])&& isset($_POST['mno'])&& isset($_POST['route'])&& isset($_POST['timings'])&& isset($_POST['latitude'])&& isset($_POST['longitude'])) {

    $rollno = $_POST['rollno'];
    $sname = $_POST['sname'];
 $regid = $_POST['regid'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
     $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $fno = $_POST['fno'];
       $mname = $_POST['mname'];
  $mno = $_POST['mno'];
   $route = $_POST['route'];
    $timings = $_POST['timings'];
     $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
      $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
    // include db connect class
  require_once('/home/a9447544/public_html/school/db_connect.php');

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO school(rollno, sname,regid, class, fname, fno, mname, mno, route, timings, latitude, longitude) VALUES('$rollno', '$sname','$regid', '$class', '$fname', '$fno', '$mname', '$mno', '$route', '$timings', '$latitude', '$longitude')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Student record has been saved successfully";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Android Java File For Creating New Record..

```
package com.example.akshay.productdata;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/9/2015.
 */

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText RollNo, SName, Class, FatherName, FatherNo, MotherName, MotherNo, RouteNo, Timings;
    String ROLLNO, SNAME, ROUTE, FATHERNAME, FATHERNO, MOTHERNAME, MOTHERNO, TIMINGS, CLASS, REGID;
    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://www.funvilla.in/school/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        RollNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_ROLL);
        SName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_SNAME);
        Class = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_CLASS);
        FatherName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_FatherName);
        FatherNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_FATHERNO);
        MotherName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_MotherName);
        MotherNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_MotherNo);
        RouteNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_Route);
        Timings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_Timings);


        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BT_SaveStudentRecord);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                ROLLNO = RollNo.getText().toString();
                SNAME = SName.getText().toString();
                CLASS = Class.getText().toString();
                FATHERNAME = FatherName.getText().toString();
                FATHERNO = FatherNo.getText().toString();
                MOTHERNAME = MotherName.getText().toString();
                MOTHERNO = MotherNo.getText().toString();
                ROUTE = RouteNo.getText().toString();
                TIMINGS = Timings.getText().toString();
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {




            String LAT = "78.555454";
            String LONG = "78.545545";
            REGID = "jefk3je3eh";
            Log.e("ROLLNO==========", ROLLNO);
            Log.e("SNAME==========", SNAME);
            Log.e("REGID==========", REGID);
            Log.e("CLASS==========", CLASS);
            Log.e("FATHERNAME==========", FATHERNAME);
            Log.e("FATHERNO==========", FATHERNO);
            Log.e("MOTHERNAME==========", MOTHERNAME);
            Log.e("MOTHERNO==========", MOTHERNO);
            Log.e("ROUTE==========", ROUTE);
            Log.e("Timings==========", TIMINGS);
            Log.e("LAT==========", LAT);
            Log.e("LONG==========", LONG);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rollno", ROLLNO));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sname", SNAME));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", REGID));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("class", CLASS));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", FATHERNAME));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fno", FATHERNO));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mname", MOTHERNAME));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mno", MOTHERNO));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("route", ROUTE));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timings", TIMINGS));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", LAT));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", LONG));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.e("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

JSONParser.java  - For Establishing connection and Saving and retrieving Records

```
package com.example.akshay.productdata;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/9/2015.
 */


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("=======" , json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/ROLLNO==========﹕ 77
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/SNAME==========﹕ lkskl
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/REGID==========﹕ jefk3je3eh
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/CLASS==========﹕ mmm
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/FATHERNAME==========﹕ sdf
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/FATHERNO==========﹕ 54554
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/MOTHERNAME==========﹕ dfd
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/MOTHERNO==========﹕ 544
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/ROUTE==========﹕ 54
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/Timings==========﹕ 5445
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/LAT==========﹕ 78.555454
08-22 00:39:39.640    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/LONG==========﹕ 78.545545
08-22 00:39:40.300    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/=======﹕ {"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."}
08-22 00:39:40.300    7279-7452/com.example.akshay.productdata E/Create Response﹕ {"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."}
```

UPDATE:

I've tried to run the query on MYSQL Database But the following error occurred

```
Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO school( rollno, sname, regid, class, fname, fno, mname, mno, route, timings, latitude, longitude ) 
VALUES ( 12, Akshay, mk34, MCA, Ajay Sood, 686, Manju Sood, 5454, 401, 55, 78.545545, 79.5421081 )

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Sood, 686, Manju Sood, 5454, 401, 55, 78.545545, 79.5421081)' at line 1
```

Comment: If mysql_query returns false, it means that the query could not be executed and most probable cause is invalid SQL. Print your SQL query, run it in mysql directly and see what the error is.

Comment: The primary Key 'id' Was not set to auto_increament .. That solves my Problem Thanks To All

Comment: In the future add or die(mysql_error()); after mysql_query(). Itt will print error messages, and exit your program, so you can see what's going on. Or for a better solution use Exceptions.

Comment: Other thing that is not related but want to say as developer that *Why TAG is not common in `Log`, We must have to understand definition of First Argument of `Log`.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use single quote '' for varchar fields in SQL query.